# Rdlc - calculate sum of columns and display total in a single cell conditionally

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

Here is the scenario, I have a dataset with fields Category, Country and NUM_SCHOOLS.
i created a column to populate the country names as columns. I created a row group to calculate the row column. In my current report Column headers(Country) Country1, Country2....so on are displayed and row headers(Category) A, B, C and D are displayed. Values is [Sum(Fields!NUM_SCHOOLS.Value)]. Everything is correctly displayed
I used pipe(|) symbol as the separator between the cells, i am not allowed to post images, i tried my best to explain. Please let me know if you need any information to help me.

Current Report:

```
      Country1     Country2
```

A        10        |      12
B         5        |       6
C         5        |       7
D        11        |      15

Required report:

```
      Country1     Country2
```

A        10        |      12
B         5        |       6
C         5        |       7
D                  26

Only for D column, i want to add the numbers and display the value as a single value. (11+15=26), for other categories it should display in different country buckets.

Please help me out. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Do you have a column group?

Comment: Sam, Yes I have a Column group Country which dynamically adds multiple columns. Row group is category.

Comment: can you use `Sum(Fields!fieldName.Value, "Country")` to get the sum of the data in your country group? Or does Country have a parent group that you can use?

Comment: Sam, Thanks! It did help to get the sum of all rows for each column, My requirement is to add up all the columns for D category and display in one single cell.

Comment: I don't understand what D is. Can you post a screenshot of your report design to `imgur.com` or somewhere..

Comment: Sam, Here is the url, Please check and let me know. http://i.imgur.com/K1ZlZNs.jpg                                       Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi Sam, Did you get a chance to look at this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. I deleted my answer though as you didn't reply after a week I figured that it probably wasn't useful or you'd worked out a way round the problem yourself. I've undeleted the answer, so you can view it again.

Comment: Sorry, I was on vacation and got back to work today! Thank you so much! Will try and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: It's cool. I just don't like to leave answers if they aren't useful :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but I don't think that you can merge columns across column groups.

I think that the best option is to remove your column grouping and manually add in 7 columns for your receipt frequencies. You'd have to use a Sum with an Iif to get your values correctly, for instance in the far left column, something like:

```
=Sum(iif(fields!RECIEPT_FREQUENCY.Value="ANNUAL" ,Fields!val.Value,0))
```

then you could add a merged cell underneath and add the following expression

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!PART_COUNT.Value="D", Fields!val.Value,0),"DataSetName")
```

---

Alternatively, you could leave it as it is and enter the following expression in a total row at the bottom of your matrix. But you would have to do something expression based for the cell borders to give the illusion of it being merged..

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!PART_COUNT.Value="D" 
And fields!RECIEPT_FREQUENCY.Value="BI-WEEKLY" 
,Fields!val.Value,0),"DataSetName")
```

Comment: Though i couldn't get the same output, your idea made me try different things and learn. I thought expressions are very tricky and tried in a different way. I have hidden the D and NONE rows from the original matrix. Added another Matrix and bound with a new dataset in which i am getting total count for D and NONE. I overlayed both the matrix on each other, that is why you could see the white border between first and second table. And also i created 7 columns in the second table and merged them to a single cell, to get the merge thing done. Thanks again for your valuable solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Sum of more than One Columns Quantity of More than one dataset in rdlc.`=Sum(Fields!QUANTITY.Value, "Tone")
+Sum(Fields!QUANTITY.Value, "Buffalo")
+Sum(Fields!QUANTITY.Value, "Cow")`